# Designing REST - save big set of related entities

Tags: json, api, rest, http

In my system, I have an entity (sales) who can serve people which have certain ZIP codes.
So, each sales can have thousands of ZIP codes binded to his account.

I need to develop REST API that would allow to load and edit list of sales zip codes.

Basically I have 2 options:

1) Creates 2 Resources : Sales and SalesZip. Submit Sales data, and then sumbit SalesZip records for each supported zip code.

2) Create Sales entity, and load list of supported zip codes like this:

```
{
    id : 1,
    name : "John",
    zip : [
        "90231",
        "12341",
        ...
    ]
}
```

And submit zip codes like an array:

```
zip[]=90231,12341
```

Both ways have some disadvantages.

If use first option, I may need to submit too many separate HTTP requests.
If use second option, I may need to send quite big PUT/POST request.

## Question

Which option should I use?
What's best practics of designing such functionality?

Answer (score 1):

What is exactly "quite big"?

In a rough estimation, if each char are 2 bytes, and your ZIP codes have 5 chars, each code is 10 bytes. Assuming that [US has 41,741 ZIP codes](http://www.zip-codes.com/zip-code-statistics.asp), in US worst case scenario, a salesman that sells across all country, would need a payload of around 417,410 bytes, or 407.6 kbytes.

In average, to how many ZIP codes a salesman belong? how is it distributed? How often do you get these requests? You may discover that is not that bad after all.

There is not enough data to make a decision, but it seems that second option is not bad.

Comment: So, second option is  a normal practice ? I can't find any examples where someone does this way))

Comment: When you upload a file, you are actually doing a very large POST, just that rather than json you use multipart content type. Imagine you are posting a file that needs to be parsed. 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net